# How to add background color to selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, haml

I have the following lists of topics added using the template as follows

```
//Template used for topic list display
%li.topic{:topic_slug => "<%=topic.slug%>", :topic_name =>"<%=topic.text%>"}
%a{href: "#!/topics/<%=topic.slug%>" }
<%= topic.text %>
```

Displayed  web app

[image]

I want to be able to select a topic and add a highlight to it. How can I do it?
I am able to select the element via the following jQuery code

```
addAllTopics: ->
    @options.topics.each(@addOneTopic)

    $(@el).find(".topics li[topic_slug=#{@options.topic}]")
```

However I am unsure how to add the highlight to the selected element. Can anyone advise me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using css method of jQuery you can add background color to any particular selected topic like this...

```
addAllTopics: ->
    @options.topics.each(@addOneTopic)

    $(@el).find(".topics li[topic_slug=#{@options.topic}]").css('background-color','#000000');
```